# URQL - GraphQL how can I get response headers

Tags: graphql, urql

I would like to read an info set in http response header when I make a query to GraphQL server.

When I execute a query with urql client, I only get these infos :

```
/** Resulting data from an [operation]{@link Operation}. */
export interface OperationResult<Data = any> {
    /** The [operation]{@link Operation} which has been executed. */
    operation: Operation;
    /** The data returned from the Graphql server. */
    data?: Data;
    /** Any errors resulting from the operation. */
    error?: CombinedError;
    /** Optional extensions return by the Graphql server. */
    extensions?: Record<string, any>;
    /** Optional stale flag added by exchanges that return stale results. */
    stale?: boolean;
}
```

Is there a way to get response headers ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71622252/using-response-of-urql can someone help me on this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71622252/using-response-of-urql Can someone help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, no, `urql` in its default behaviour does not expose the response headers of a request as can be seen here: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql/blob/master/packages/core/src/internal/fetchSource.ts#L23-L29
It's simply swallowed.

The long answer is, if your replace the `fetchExchange` with a custom implementation you can extract whatever information you want. Unfortunately that's obviously custom and some work, but on the other hand, `urql` allows for you to drill into its internals and swap this behaviour out.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a wrong answer. See , you can simply wrap `fetch` to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `fetch` wrapper in the provided client (If it's global to your app) or on in a specific client in a component with the `fetch` option like this:

```
  const client = createClient({
    url: `https://example.org/graphql`,
    fetch: (...args) =>
      fetch(...args).then((response) => {
        const myHeader = response.headers.get('my-header');
        if (myHeader) {
          /* do stuff */
        }

        return response;
      }),
    fetchOptions: { credentials: 'include' },
    …
  });
```

Comment: This will raise me a cors error

Comment: @LucasMiguel CORS error mainly comes from the backend, not front. You may need to allow queries from the app domain and/or add the custom header in the allowed headers?